# Azure - Trying to join VM to domain using JsonADDomainExtension in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Trying to join Azure CentOS VM to existing AD Domain. But, it fails. Error message is cryptic and not helpful.

Tried to join Azure CentOS VM to existing AD Domain using JsonADDomainExtension in Terraform.  I have tried the following so far,

- Manually, I could join VM to domain using 'realm join'
- Tried TF code without OUPath -> doesn't help

---

Code is very similar to that of https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-domain-join-existing/azuredeploy.json

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "adjoin" {
  name                 = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.testextn01.name}-adjoin"
  location             = "${azurerm_resource_group.testextn.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.testextn.name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.testextn01.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "JsonADDomainExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.3"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "Name": "NEXT.CLOUD.COM",
        "User": "DOMAIN\\ad-join",
        "OUPath": "\"OU=Centos,OU=Servers,OU=Operations,DC=NEXT,DC=CLOUD,DC=COM\"",
        "Restart": "true",
        "Options": "3"
    }
SETTINGS
  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
      "Password": "topsecret"
    }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS

}
```

---

Terraform apply was not returning back the prompt,

---

azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.adjoin: Still creating... (1h26m21s elapsed)
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.adjoin: Still creating... (1h26m31s elapsed)
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.adjoin: Still creating... (1h26m41s elapsed)
^CInterrupt received.
Please wait for Terraform to exit or data loss may occur.
Gracefully shutting down...
stopping operation...

---

Error message reads as below in /var/log/waagent.log file,

---

2019/07/18 05:06:41.630295 ERROR ExtHandler Event: name=Microsoft.Compute.JsonADDomainExtension, op=Install, message=eJytkcFKxDAURff9ivcBTtK0ndZ2N9gRR3B0PxTJJOkQaPJKkmrHrzdUFBcKMrh8i3s4993Ddg7Keo126xy6DvZoV2/KIahZBxAoVQMsq65AWx/4MBBhZHLwQeIUuiRLWU3TirJrSNdNWjZ5Tco0q6oSdvvbR4j0O27loBxspFQSnnYtsHVRQEAQJ4fTCNSfPe09/TipGCf6ygdtp5mflA1EfRp6+qCFQ499IDdoxikocu/RbtoWDdf2q8ozIznJfpHL86K+WM4og+78T37J8kflXJfQF+7ooI+RvED/SlotJPptmwaimgLWwFHbHzNROG4q0JhYHiwG6HGyMnkHeGWxYg==, duration=0

---

Error message is clueless and not of much help.

Comment: Any process on your side?

Comment: Tried what you suggested on **OUPath**, it didn't really help. Have you tried joining CentOS/Linux VM to AD using this extension ?

Comment: Please check my update, your linking template is used to join an existing Windows virtual machine into an existing Windows Active Directory Domain. so it's nope for CentOS VM

Comment: If my reply is helpful, you could accept it as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may take attention to the user and **OUPath** format in your `settings`, it should not have the `"\`, you could change it to `"OUPath":"OU=Centos,OU=Servers,OU=Operations,DC=NEXT,DC=CLOUD,DC=COM",`

Also, you could add `depends_on` in the extension block as the extension creation replies on the VM generation. You could get more references about using Terraform to join a new Azure Virtual Machine to a Domain from [this1](https://pixelrobots.co.uk/2019/03/use-terraform-to-join-a-new-azure-virtual-machine-to-a-domain/) and [this2](https://jackstromberg.com/2018/11/using-terraform-with-azure-vm-extensions/).

### Update

In fact, your [linking template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-domain-join-existing) is used to join an existing **Windows virtual machine** into an existing Windows Active Directory Domain.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per the highlight in the image in the other answer the JsonADDomainExtension is only for Windows.

In order to join a Linux (CentOS/RHEL/Ubuntu/etc) VM you would need to use a custom `#cloud-init` `runcmd` (supports a list of shell commands to run, but don't embed secrets if you can help it) or `#include` with a URL to a domain joining shell script into a `customData` parameter to your VM creation, or use the `CustomScriptExtension` to execute a shell script that joins your VM to the domain after it is created.

See an example of the CustomScriptExtension in this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64981397