# Domain Join Azure Linux VM with ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-linux

Is there any way we can domain join Azure Linux VM with ARM template? Like we have domain join extension for Azure Windows VM?

Or any other way to achieve this in ARM template?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the way to solve this using custom script extension:

ARM will look like :

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
  "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'/joindomain')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "comments": "CustomScript - JsonADDomainExtension",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
    "type": "CustomScript",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
    "settings": {
      "fileUris": [
        "[concat(uri(deployment().properties.templateLink.uri, 'script.sh')
      ]
    },
    "protectedSettings": {
      "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh script.sh ',parameters('domainName'), ' ', parameters('domainJoinUserName'), ' ', parameters('domainJoinUserPassword'))]"
    }
  }
}
```

Script.sh will look like :

```
echo $3 | sudo realm join $1 -U $2
sudo authconfig --enablesssd --enablesssdauth --enablemkhomedir --update
```

Comment: how do you pass ou path ?